# How to copy an image to application folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I already know how to browse for an image using open file dialog. So let's say we already got the path :

`string imagePath = "Desktop/Images/SampleImage.jpg";`

I want to copy that file, into my application folder :

`string appFolderPath = "SampleApp/Images/";`

How to copy the given image to the `appFolderPath` programmatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    "Images",
    fileName);
File.Copy(imagePath, path);
```

where `fileName` is the actual name of the file only (including the extension).

**UPDATE:** the [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will cleanly combine strings into a well-formed path. For example, if one of the strings *does* have a backslash and the other *doesn't* it won't matter; they are combined appropriately.

The [System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), per MSDN, does the following:

> Gets the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies.

That's going to be the executable path you're running in; so the path in the end (and let's assume `fileName` is `test.txt`) would be:

```
{path_to_exe}\Images\test.txt
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what it's meant by `Path.Combine` and `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`? Thank you.

Comment: Wait, is `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` used to get the folder path of the application `.exe`? Thanks.

Comment: Oh nice thanks, I just posted my analysis on the comment at the same time you updated your post, it seems match. Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string path="Source imagepath";

  File.Copy(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"\\Images", path);
```

\ System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is to provide path of the application folder

Comment: You seem correct, but Michael's answer is more complete. So I'll accept Michael's. Thank you for your answer